# HTML/CSS: Content Div slips down

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, html

i have a simple markup with a navigation `div`, a content `div` and a footer `div`.
If I open my "page", everything seems okay. But if I open the page and then resize the browser window to e.g. 30%, then the **content** `div` slides down.

It seems only to occur in internet explorer.

The test markup:

```
<html> 
<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="navi" style="float:left;width:197px;background-color:blue;">
  NaviContent
  <br /><br />
  more NaviContent
 </div>

 <div id="content" style="width:820px;background-color:yellow">

  <table>

    <tr>
        <td>Content
            <br /><br />
            more ContentContent
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            more ContentContent
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            more ContentContent
        </td>
    </tr>

 </table>

 </div>

 <div id="footer" style="clear:both;">
 Footer Content
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Images of the problem:

browser in 100% view:
http://www.suckmypic.net/25729/1.png

browser window resized: http://www.suckmypic.net/25730/2.png

*Please help*

Comment: Try setting `float: left` on your `#content` div too, or set both containers to `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your #container a width

Answer (score 0):

This is because sum content + navi > window width.